# Proof that $\sin x=4^{-x/\pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\binom{4x/\pi}{2n+1}$ for $x\ge 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, binomial-theorem

Is there any proof of the identity
$$\sin x=4^{-x/\pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\binom{4x/\pi}{2n+1}$$
where $x\ge 0$?

If we replace $4x/\pi$ by $x$ and write the binomial in terms of the falling factorial $(x)_n$, we get
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(x)_{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!},$$
which is remarkably similar to the power series for $\sin x$ centered at $0$:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\sin\pars{x}
\vphantom{A^{A}}\,\right\vert_{\ x\ \geq\ 0}\,\,\, =\,\,\,
4^{-x/\pi}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}
{4x/\pi \choose 2n + 1}}:\ {\Large ?}}$.

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{4^{-x/\pi}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}{4x/\pi \choose 2n + 1}} =
-\,4^{-x/\pi}\,\,\,\ic\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\ic^{2n + 1}
{4x/\pi \choose 2n + 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,4^{-x/\pi}\,\,\,\ic\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\ic^{n}
{4x/\pi \choose n}{1 - \pars{-1}^{n} \over 2} =
4^{-x/\pi}\,\,\,\Im\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\ic^{n}
{4x/\pi \choose n}
\\[5mm] = &\
4^{-x/\pi}\,\,\,\Im\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\ic^{n}
\,{\Gamma\pars{4x/\pi + 1} \over
\Gamma\pars{n + 1}\Gamma\pars{4x/\pi - n + 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
4^{-x/\pi}\,\,\,\Im\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\ic^{n}\
{\Gamma\pars{4x/\pi + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{n + 1}}
\ \times
\\[1mm] &\ \phantom{4^{-x/\pi}\,\,\,\Im\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}}
{\Gamma\pars{n - 4x/\pi}\sin\pars{\pi\bracks{n - 4x/\pi}} \over \pi}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{4^{-x/\pi}\,\,\sin\pars{4x} \over \pi}\,\Im\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-\ic}^{n}\
{\Gamma\pars{n - 4x/\pi}\Gamma\pars{4x/\pi + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{n + 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{4^{-x/\pi}\,\,\sin\pars{4x} \over \pi}\,\Im
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-\ic}^{n}
\int_{0}^{1}t^{n - 4x/\pi - 1}\,\,\pars{1 - t}^{4x/\pi}
\,\,\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{4^{-x/\pi}\,\,\sin\pars{4x} \over \pi}\,\Im
\int_{0}^{1}t^{-4x/\pi - 1}\,\,\pars{1 - t}^{4x/\pi}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\pars{-\ic t}^{n}\,\,\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
{4^{-x/\pi}\,\,\sin\pars{4x} \over \pi}\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}
{t^{-4x/\pi}\,\,\pars{1 - t}^{4x/\pi} \over
1 + t^{2}}\dd t}
_{\ds{4^{x/\pi}\,\pi\,\csc\pars{4x}\color{red}{\sin\pars{x}}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\sin\pars{x}} \\ &
\end{align}

---

The last integral is straightforward evaluated with the change $\ds{{1 - t \over t} \mapsto t}$.

Comment: Very clean, very nice work.

Answer (score 2):

Start with:
$$
(1+z)^A = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{A}{n}z^n
$$Split this into even and odd pieces:
$$
(1+z)^A =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{A}{2n+1}z^{2n+1}+ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{A}{2n}z^{2n}
$$Playing around with the even-only piece (exercise!), we have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{A}{2n}z^{2n}=\frac{1}{2} \left((1-z)^A+(1+z)^A\right)
$$So,
$$
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{A}{2n+1}z^{2n} =\frac{(1+z)^A-(1-z)^A}{2 z};
$$put $z=i$, $A=4x/\pi$ and try and simplify it using Euler's Formula.